# Received Error Passing in Parameter for React Navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, apollo, apollo-client

I am using react native, typescript and apollo api for my project.

I am trying to pass in a parameter for navigation features. The problem I encounter is

```
Type '({ route }: { route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Data1">; }) => Element | null' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "Data1"> | undefined'.
  Type '({ route }: { route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Data1">; }) => Element | null' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'route' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Data1">; }'.ts(2322)
Data1.tsx(45, 29): 'route' is declared here.
types.d.ts(318, 5): The expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteConfig<ParamListBase, "Data1", StackNavigationState<ParamListBase>, NativeStackNavigationOptions, NativeStackNavigationEventMap>'
```

based on this line of code

```
<Stack.Screen name="Data1" component={Data1}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
```

I have defined RootStackParamList as follows

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined,
  Data1:  { rocketID: string },
}
```

and also imported the parameter as follows

```
function Data1({ route }: { route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'Data1'> }) {

  const { rocketID } = route.params
```

But in the end I don't know what error this is and I can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I had the same problem, have you already solved it?
i change "Home: undefined" to "Home: any," Error messages disappear, but I know this is not best practice.